# AngularJS - templateUrl path appended to href path

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting up a very simple AngularJS application and am running into a minor, yet frustrating, issue.  Here is the sample application using $routeProvider:

```
angular.module('thought', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/thought', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/thought/posts.html',
            controller: ThoughtCntl
        }).
        when('/thought/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/thought/edit.html',
            controller: EditCntl
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/thought'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Here is the content of posts.html:

```
<div>
<button>Create</button>

<div>
    <h3>Posts</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in publishedPosts">
            <a href="/thought/edit/{{post._id}}">{{post.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to /thought, posts.html loads with the appropriate data content.  The the  link contains 'href=localhost:8080/thought/edit/1234' as it should.  However, when I click the link, it attempts to load the template from 'localhost:8080/thought/edit/partials/thought/edit.html'.  The templateUrl path is appended to the href path.  I'm sure that something simple is mis-configured, but I can't find it.  Any ideas what I should look at?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try setting a templateUrl starting with "/" ? maybe it's being set relative to the current url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<base>` tag :

```
<base href="/" />
```